# HEC-RAS "station-elevation" CSV format

Tags: hec-ras

I'm working with "station-elevation" CSV format from regional database. They provide the file with the geometry of the section as usually rappresented in HEC-RAS and progressive distance along river reach. I also have created a georeferenced rapresentation of river reach on QGIS, wich perfectly align with DTM. I would like to match CSV with geometry section with river georef. geometry.

I'm trying using a CSV with "River Station", "Station", "Elevation" but it doesn't match with the real river geometry. When I add the CSV the river geometry loses his coordinates and section aren't in the right place.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What are you using to get the georeferenced river reach and cross sections? it seems from your text that you do not address that part. Have you given a try to the plug-in RiverGIS?